# In-class / constructor member initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, raii

I'll try to summarize what I need in both words and code snippets.

I have a class, `Foo`, which contains a data member of the type `Bar`:

```
class Foo {
  public:

    Bar instance_of_Bar;

    Foo (int some_data) 
    {
      // I need to initialize instance_of_Bar using one of its
      // constructors here, but I need to do some processing first


      // This is highly discouraged (and I prefer not to use smart pointers here)
      instance_of_bar = Bar(..);
      // As an unrelated question: will instance_of_Bar be default-initialized 
      // inside the constructor before the above assignment?
    }
}
```

Obviously, the "correct" way to do it would be to use an initializer list like this:

```
Foo (int some_data) : instance_of_Bar(some_data) {}
```

But this is not an option because I need to do some work on `some_data` before passing it to the `Bar` constructor.

Hopefully I made myself clear. What would be the RAII way of doing it with minimal overhead and copying (The `Bar` class is a hefty one).

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: `new Bar(..);` is wrong BTW.

Comment: Of course, I meant general dynamical allocation. I fixed the code snippet (I'm aware that it's poor practice, just trying to point out an obvious alternative).

Comment: I't all not necessary, you can use a temporary instance to copy from: `instance_of_bar = Bar(...);`.

Comment: Edited my question again. Thanks for the correction. It's important for me to edit my questions so that people who stumble across them don't pick up bad coding practices.

Just one question about this method, is the temp instance allocated on the stack and destroyed automatically or will this leak memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"But this is not an option because I need to do some work on some_data before passing it to the Bar constructor."*

What about providing another function to *"do some work on `some_data`"*:

```
 Foo (int some_data) : instance_of_Bar(baz(some_data)) {}

 int baz(int some_data) {
     // do some work
     return some_data;
 }
```